# How do I program bootstrap-3 pagination to work with simple HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm working in a "News" Section, and trying to make a bootstrap 3 pagination work with jquery.

HTML for the pagination:

```
<nav class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="pag_prev">
            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="pag_1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li class="pag_next">
            <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $("#pag_1").addClass("active");
});

pageSize = 1;
var i = 1;

showPage = function(page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });
}

showPage(i);


$("#pagin li.numeros").click(function() {
    $("#pagin li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    i = parseInt($(this).text());
    showPage(i);
});

$("#pagin li.pag_prev").click(function() {
    $("#pagin li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    i = i - 1;
    showPage(i);
});

$("#pagin li.pag_next").click(function() {
    $("#pagin li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    i = i + 1;
    showPage(i);
});
```

I have 5 news for now, so I set the news per page in 1 (`pageSize = 1;`) so I can have 5 pages to navigate and make sure its working.

My issues are:

1. When I navigate the pages with the arrows (not the numbers), the numbers don't get the `active` class, and I couldnt figurate how to make it.
2. Im showing 5 pages, but you can navigate to infinite foward and backward, I don't know how to tell to stop when reach the last and the first page.
3. Is there a way to automatic generate a new `<li class="numeros"><a href="#">Nº</a></li>` and the respective page with JS when the page reach the amount of news setting (e.x. `pageSize = 5`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I navigate the pages with the arrows (not the numbers), the numbers dont get the "active" class, and I couldnt figurate how to make it.

You should first check which *"number"* is actualy `active`, then add `active` class the next number (if `pag_next` is clicked) or to the previous number (if `pag_prev` is clicked).

```
$(".pagination li.pag_prev").click(function() {
    // ...
    // instead of this (as "this" is the arrow):
    // $(this).addClass("active");
    // remove active class of the current number and add the class to previous number:
    $('.numeros.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');

    // ...
});

$(".pagination li.pag_next").click(function() {
    // ...
    // instead of this (as "this" is the arrow):
    // $(this).addClass("active");
    // remove active class of the current number and add the class to next number:
    $('.numeros.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

    // ...
});
```

---

> Im showing 5 pages, but you can navigate to infinite foward and backward, i don't know how to tell to stop when reach the last and the first page.

You should simply check if the *first* or *last* pagination number already has class `active`, then `return` (do nothing) if one of them has:

```
$(".pagination li.pag_prev").click(function() {
    // make sure that the active pagination number is not the first.
    // we want to return here (do nothing) if the first number is already active:
    if($(this).next().is('.active')) return;
    // ...
    // continue executing if the first number isn't yet active:
    currentPage--;
    showPage();
});

$(".pagination li.pag_next").click(function() {
    // make sure that the active pagination number is not the last.
    // we want to return here (do nothing) if the last number is already active:
    if($(this).prev().is('.active')) return;
    // ...
    // continue executing if the last number isn't yet active:
    currentPage++;
    showPage();
});
```

---

> Is there a way to automatic generate a new Nº and the respective page with JS when the page reach the amount of news setting (e.x. pageSize = 5)?

Yes.

First, we need some more variables:

```
// news per page:
var pageSize = 1;
// total news (count elements with "content" class):
var pagesCount = $(".content").length;
// calculate total pages:
var totalPages = Math.ceil(pagesCount / pageSize);

// I have replaced "i" variable with "currentPage" (more details at the bottom)
var currentPage = 1;
```

We already know the `totalPages` and `pageSize`, so we can create pagination dynamically based on total amount of news and the number of news per page:

HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="pag_prev">
        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- our dynamic pagination content goes here -->
    <li class="pag_next">
        <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var nav = '';
for (var s=0; s<totalPages; s++){
    nav += '<li class="numeros"><a href="#">'+(s+1)+'</a></li>';
}
// append pagination numbers after "prev" button:
$(".pag_prev").after(nav);
// add "active" class to the first pagination number:
$(".numeros").first().addClass("active");
```

---

As a side note, your `i` variable is set in a global scope, so you don't have to pass it every time to the `showPage()` method and you can use it direclty.
I renamed this variable to something more *"readable"* - `currentPage`:

```
var currentPage = 1;

showPage = function() {
    $(".content").hide().each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (currentPage - 1) && n < pageSize * currentPage)
            $(this).show();
    });
}

showPage();
```

---

**Whole code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhyxbr3r/)**